# Proof of $ \arg (G(j \omega))=-\omega\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right) $

Tags: complex-numbers

We have this formula:
$$
\displaystyle \arg (G(j \omega))=-\omega\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)
$$

(We understand the amplitude of course, please help us to find a proof for the phase shift)

[image]

without a proof (control theory course).
Can someone remind us how it is calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not that hard in the end!

We consider the time points when the two curves passes 0:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin \left(\omega t_{1}\right) &=0 \\
K \sin \left(\omega t_{2}+\phi\right) &=0
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\Longrightarrow \omega t_{1} = \omega t_{2}+\phi \\
\phi = \omega t_{1} - \omega t_{2} \\
\phi = -\omega(t_2-t_1)
$$